# ln -nfs blocked by Apache

Tags: apache, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy a PHP application. When the script update the document root of apache, which is a link, to the new directory with the new code, the ln command does nothing:

```
ln -nfs /sites/app/dir/releases/20110305165826 /sites/app/dir/current
```

I had to remove it and re-run the command, but by doing that Apache (of course) did not liked it and the home page is now blank.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

please check rights of deploy user and apache runner users, they should best be the same user but it might also work with the same group and correct umask and file rights